# How to debug a battery issue?

Tags: battery, htc-sensation

I have HTC Sensation 4G. I have a very peculiar issue with the battery. I've been using the phone for just over one year now. There are some periods (about 7 to 15 days) when battery performance is absolutely fine.

But then after certain days of good performance battery starts behaving weirdly: Phone gets switched off even at over 60% battery. Restarting it shows about 5% battery, again switches off, restart shows around 20% etc.

So I guessed there is some calibration issue. **Taking out the battery at the time of this erratic behavior makes it work fine for a little while** (half an hour to a couple of hours) then again the stupidity starts. I have tried draining the battery to 0% and then a full charge, tried various usage models (not using wifi, disabling animations to reduce usage etc.) nothing seems to work.

I can't properly debug this issue properly as connecting to computer starts charging and when its charging there are no such issues. This is **REALLY** frustrating, Any one has any idea how to debug it?

(I have come to know that certain batch of HTC sensation has this issue, not everyone has experienced similar problems but there are people and no one has been able to point me in the right direction)

Comment: Instead of investing too much energy (LOL), have you thought about just buying a replacement on ebay? (BG58100 or BA-S560 battery model). Here in the EU this costs only about 7-13EUR. It'll bring you back the runtime of a new battery as a side effect.

Comment: Yes i'm getting a replacement but this weird bug, well it bugs me! Before I switch to the new battery i would like to at least give a shot at debugging or try to know the cause of this problem

Answer (score 2):

I have diagnosed several battery related anomalies with a combination of two apps: one called [Diagnosis](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.diagnosis) and the other [GSam Battery Monitor Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsamlabs.bbm.pro).  GSam isn't as robust but it offers a greater filtering options to sort the culprits by CPU usage, power usage, memory usage....  In every case it turned out to be a problem with an app or a setting or my current ROM but those apps helped me track down the problem.

You may also want to check your device's logs for clues.  You can use [aLogrec](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogrec) to record your [logcat](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Logcat), then note the time of a spontaneous shutdown then check the log to see what events lead up to it.  I can barely understand what is contained in my logcat but [this forum post may help you](http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/141073-learn-logcat-like-pro.html).

Comment: I'm using log cat, not able to find anything useful. I'll try out Diagnosis.

Comment: I updated my answer, I got confused and didn't realize that I used GSam along with Diagnosis each time.  Basically GSam allowed me find the problem and then Diagnosis allowed me to drill down to the specific process that was going rouge.