# Android 4.1.1 consumes too much memory

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, ram

My HTC One S has been upgraded to 4.1.1 and I noticed that it started consuming too much memory.

When I had 4.0, average memory consumption was about 300-450 MB. But now it is on the level of 700-850 MB. Is this a normal situation for the current version of Android or did something go wrong after the upgrade?

All system apps were upgraded with the OS. I have 1 GB of RAM.

Comment: Have you a record of how much memory the apps used to use, and how much they use now?

Comment: I experienced the same problems when my htc one x updated from ICS to 4.1. With ics it barely used half of the 1g ram and everything was fast and smooth. Now with JB it is almost always using 900m and no way near as fast or smooth and will freeze up sometimes and the only thing that helps is clearing memory. I have installed the update and did a complete wipe after trying to resolve the freezes.

Answer (score 1):

This could count as a good sign: There should not be such a thing as "unused RAM". Linux and Android in special do a good job to make the best use of it by caching things. If there is any RAM not currently needed by running apps, it can be used to keep e.g. pieces of the file system for faster access -- which also helps to save battery life. Once there is additional RAM needed, those caches are the first things to be cleared.

For more details, I recommend to take a look at the following related questions and their answers:

- [0 ram free on ICS](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/36828/16575)
- [Are there guidelines on how much free RAM a phone should have?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20032/16575)

Comment: I read the answers in the links above and have a question: will not it degrade performance by clearing that RAM for a new app? If the RAM is free it could simply occupy it, but now unused RAM has to be freed up first and then to be occupied.

Comment: Au contraire. It would degrade performance if you'd permantly kill apps, and they had to be loaded again: I/O reading from the (slower) storage, initializing the app, etc. And by killing the app you would also "clear" that RAM (just to have it re-filled by the re-starting app in most cases). Leave that headache to the system :) The only things which *might* need some adjustment (in some cases) are OOM values (i.e. the configuration of the system behind this).

Comment: what is OOM values? Honestly, I had asked the question about memory usage because I felt that my htc is working a bit slower than with previuos version

Comment: See e.g. [Auto Memory Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lim.android.automemman), which serves this issue. But "feeling slower after update/upgrade" can have many reasons (never version might need more ressources, update can have "messed up" something, etc.pp.).