# Why Large RAM use with my Galaxy Nexus verizon while Little RAM use with Galaxy Nexus GSM?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, ram

Galaxy Nexus verizon

ROM:10.2-20131017-SKANK-toro

[image: Skank]

Galaxy Nexus GSM

ROM:CM11

[image: CM11]

From the picture, you can see that verizon system uses a large amount RAM while GSM not. Why that happend? And recently on my verizon phone I cannot even start a new app because of RAM runs out.

Comment: Comparing apples with oranges? What exactly is the question here? And where's the issue? There is [no such thing as "unused RAM"](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/36850/16575) on *nix-based systems.

Comment: do both phones have exactly the same apps installed and running?

Comment: Also, you're comparing stock ROM (Verizon) vs CyanogenMod (GSM). I vote to close this question.

Comment: @geffchang Verizon is using unofficial CM 10.2 too. And I add more details. The question is that I cannot understand why verizon Android system use so much RAM. And Sorry for not expressing my question.

Comment: @Izzy The question is Why verizon Android system use so much RAM while GSM not.

Comment: Are you lacking RAM? Have you checked the answer I linked above, as to how RAM is utilized on *nix systems? How much is used depends on many criteria, not only what apps are running.

Comment: You're comparing two completely different versions of Android here. One of the goals in KitKat was to reduce its memory footprints so that it would run suitably on older, less powerful devices. If nothing else, this is probably just a result of Google's efforts in that regard. It may have nothing whatsoever to do with the Verizon vs GSM fact.

Answer (score 2):

As I've already explained in [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/36850/16575), on *nix based systems there's no such thing as "unused RAM". How RAM is utilized, depends on many criteria:

- what apps are running (foreground, background, services...)
- how active they are (program structures, data loaded)
- how much file I/O there is (data from "slower storage" gets cached in RAM for faster access)

are only some of them. Follow up to the other asnwer to find out how to get additional details about caches and buffers used in RAM.

Comment: I will check. Really thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to factory reset your phone or do that from CWM after wiping dalvik, cache and system data.

And consider going to CM11 on your Verizon Gnexus too Android 4.4 has better RAM management and task killing.

I am saying that your system is behaving very differently so may be aome bug but most probably virus or something which cannot be specifically detected so I suggest thoroughly wiping your system.

Comment: This does not answer the question presented by eiverne.

Comment: Because the both have different ROMS and something is not right with the Verizon's custom ROM so why not install another and advanced build.

Comment: @coolhz I have flashed new CM 11 to verizon one. And it become better now. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: thank you and please vote up some one has voted my answer down please I am new to stack exchange this will help my profile . your wish.