# 100% RAM Used.what to do?

Tags: stock-android, ram

i have huawei g5000-5000 mobile whith 512 mb ram which has 479 mb free and a quad-core processor.offlate i have seen it has 0mb free ram and i am not able to do any work.whenever i open any app it automatically closes.
i dont have many app heavy game and no heavy app loaded on my phone.i jjst have whatsapp,ucbrowser,truecaller,etc which i think should not be a problem.
i have an unrooted phone.so please tell me what to do?

Comment: Please take a look at: [Are there guidelines on how much free RAM a phone should have?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20032/16575) / [0 ram free on ICS](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/36828/16575) / our [ram tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/ram/info).

Answer (score 1):

On android/Linux free RAM is wasted RAM. Most of the used RAM should be used for caching applications. Depending on the rest of your phone's hardware it may also have simply not enough RAM as I think a quad-core processor is often used together with other decent hardware.
If an app closes then your android system especially the LMK (low memory killer) misconfigured because it should kill other background processes to allow the foreground application to run. This may fail if only system applications are running which cannot be closed that easily. Then rebooting may be one option before rooting and changing internal settings.