# Does clearing RAM actually help in performance before opening a game?

Tags: reboot, ram, performance, android-11, google-play-games

I have the samsung a32 5g.

Is it a good idea to clear RAM often on your phone? I have 4GB total and notice it is always usually using 2GB, and 3GB when I have opened apps recently. To prevent app game crashes and increase performance, does cleaning RAM actually help? Should you turn off auto-clean since it might close apps you wanted open and would be more inconvenient than helpful?

Does cleaning RAM manually work the same way a phone restarts and "cleans" RAM or is it different?

Comment: Our [ram tag-wiki](/tags/ram/info) answers that. TL;DR: No, it's a bad idea. Let the system take care for the RAM. "Cleaning" RAM has the opposite effect. Related answered questions: [0 ram free on ICS](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/36828/16575) // [Are there guidelines on how much free RAM a phone should have?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20032/16575)

Comment: I see, though I noticed Pokemon go seems to crash often when I re-open the app and maybe it's a placebo effect but cleaning up RAM manually when it's at 3GB/4GB seems to help keep the game from crashing too often. I read that the system is smooth and can manage RAM when needed, but if you are seeing performance drops would it not be a bad idea or will it still do nothing? Is it ever useful in any situation like if you opened multiple apps in one day?

Comment: That's most likely rather a bug in the app. You could send the app developer a log of the crash (if the app offers that; but I rather suspect it has a bunch of trackers inside and one of those will already have taken care for this, so the dev already sees it in the developer console). Of course if you know about such an issue, and clearing RAM makes it work, it might be considered a viable work-around until the issue got solved – but then apply it only when needed, i.e. when you need to re-open the app as described.